# How can you change Firefox 25's Network Info Popups?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

I noticed a change in Firefox 25 beta, soon to be released: Go to chrome://browser/content/devtools/webconsole.xul, view source, and in the current Firefox (24) you see:

```
<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
        id="devtools-webconsole"
        macanimationtype="document"
        fullscreenbutton="true"
        title="&window.title;"
        browserConsoleTitle="&browserConsole.title;"
        windowtype="devtools:webconsole"
        width="900" height="350"
        persist="screenX screenY width height sizemode">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome://global/content/globalOverlay.js"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="webconsole.js"/>

  <commandset id="editMenuCommands"/>
...
```

In Firefox 25, however, the reference to webconsole.js is replaced with an inline script, function goUpdateConsoleCommands() with two goUpdateCommand calls.

[Devtools-tweaks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/devtools-tweaks/) is not working for the network popup now, because the webconsole.js link no longer exists on that window. The code here has nothing to modify to change the popup: https://github.com/programmin1/DevTools-Tweaks/blob/master/content/netWinOverlay.js

Is there any easy way to re-hook this functionality into the network popup? Will JSON/xml parsing be introduced in Firefox soon, making this unnecessary?

Comment: Are you the author of this add-on? If you are not, you should file at the very least an [issue](https://github.com/programmin1/DevTools-Tweaks/issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebConsoleFrame` stuff was ported to the add-on SDK loader in [bug 877262](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/497504e7f952).

Judging from the code, the following should give access to the `WebConsoleFrame` the add-on "uses":

```
var {devtools} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Loader.jsm", {});
var {WebConsoleFrame} = devtools.require("devtools/webconsole/webconsole");
```

As for the second part of your question: Will the devtools support the same stuff natively?

I'm not sure. You should get in touch with the devtools team and ask them and have a look at the existing bugs: [Open devtools bugs containing "json"](http://mzl.la/17fXDy0). And/or file a new enhancement bug.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems this doesn't work with Addon SDK, do you know if that's possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957176