# Addon SDK error getting devtools module

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools, jsm

I'm adding this code to a Addon-SDK addon:

```
var {devtools} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Loader.jsm", {});
var {WebConsoleFrame} = devtools.require("devtools/webconsole/webconsole");
```

Although this works in a normal (old style) addon, with `cfx run` I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: unable to satisfy: require(devtools/webconsole/webconsole) from
(thefilename.js)
```

To clarify, I'm trying to add those 2 lines into here: https://github.com/DavidBruant/usefulStackTrace/blob/master/lib/trackStack.js

Is this not possible within the Addon SDK's restartless addon system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick-and-not-so-dirty workaround

```
var {WebConsoleFrame} = devtools["require"]("devtools/webconsole/webconsole");
```

Comment: Wow! How did you know to do this? This works, although it should be exactly the same as my second line. Maybe `cfx` is over-checking things somehow?

Comment: It's not a matter of javascript. During the build process a python script checks the source code for `require`s. The regular expression used catches the dot notation. So using the bracket notation gives you a free pass.

Comment: yeah, the cfx python script is being a little overzealous in its validation. Glad to see this work-around!